# how to connect to asp.net web service in android?

Tags: android, asp.net

I want to call asp.net web service in android so that it can make the validation in back end. I want to make an app. which calls the web service in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wsdl2code.com - it generates all the needed code from your wsdl to iphone and android native code! it works great for me

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download ksoap2 android jar.Then right click to your project folder in Eclipse. Click properties, then java **build path > libraries > add external jar**.Then write code as..

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(YOUR_CONNECTION_NAMESPACE, methodName);

    //add parameters to web service method..
request.addProperty(parameterName, parameterValue);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(YOUR_CONNECTION_URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(YOUR_ACTION_NAME, envelope);

result = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
```

A very good tutorial over this topic is..

- [Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap)